# I can't access my asked question anymore?

Tags: support, status-completed, asking-questions, new-users

I asked a question as a guest, with my name as `Navik` and later on decided to register on the website. So I went ahead and now I'm a registered user but I have now lost access to the question that I had asked before registering.

What do I do?

Comment: [Is this the one](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8304/where-can-i-find-the-authetic-and-complete-vedas-online-hindi-english)?

Comment: No. That is the question that I had asked AFTER signing up. The question that I'm trying to gain access to is [this one](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8298/can-a-24-year-old-renounce-the-material-world-and-live-a-life-solely-dedicated-t/)

Comment: I will set a request to merge those accounts, give me some time

Comment: Thank you @Mr. Alien

Comment: Posted your request, should be processed in a day or two

Comment: The accounts have been successfully merged. Thank you for your help, Mr. Alien

Comment: Great, you welcome...